# Java set XStream deserialization rules

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

I have some class with codeBased `enum` filed. And I have xml serealized object of this class. But when I try to deserialize this xml with `XStream` I receive:

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No enum constant com.functest.util.TriState.0 : No enum constant com.functest.util.TriState.0

Class

```
class Params{
   String clientCode;
   TriState triState;
}
```

xmlParameters String

```
<Params>
    <clientCode>1516001</clientCode>
    <triState>0</triState>
</Params>
```

`TriState`

```
enum TriState implements codeBased{
    YES(1);
    NO(0);
    UNDEFINED(-1);

    int code;

    TriState fromCode(int code){
         if(code == 1) return YES;
         if(code == 0) return NO;
         return UNDEFINED;
    }
}
```

And I try to deserialize xml like this:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.alias("triState", TriState.class);
Params p = (Params) xStream.fromXML(xmlParameters);
```

How can I set deserialization rules to get value from xml and invoke enums method `fromCode(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Transform your fromCode into a static method :

```
public enum TriState {
    YES(1),NO(0),UNDEFINED(-1);
    int code;
    private TriState(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public static TriState fromCode(int code) {
        if (code == 1)
            return YES;
        if (code == 0)
            return NO;
        return UNDEFINED;
    }
}
```

And define a Converter that uses the static method to transform the code to a valid enum:

```
public class TriStateConverter implements Converter {
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return TriState.class==type;
    }
    public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext mc) {
        writer.setValue(Integer.toString(((TriState)o).code));
    }
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext uc) {
        return TriState.fromCode(Integer.parseInt(reader.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Haven't tried the code, but it should work.